# Python Bokeh donut chart category, subcategory mean calculation

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization, bokeh, data-science

I am using the following code to draw a bokeh donut chart to visualize the mean prices across different categories and subcategories.

```
d = Donut(train.groupby(['main_cat','sub_cat']).price.mean(), hover_text='mean',width=500,height=500)
show(d)
```

For sub_cat, the values are calculated correctly, but for main_cat, instead of showing the mean for main_cat, it is showing the sum of means of sub_cat under the particular main_cat. What change either in bokeh code or python code should be made to correctly show the mean values main_cat? 
Your support is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There probably is not a way. `Donut` was part of the old `bokeh.charts` API that was deprecated and sub sequently removed from Bokeh last year. In particular, any problems, issues, or missing features will never receive any additional work. It is abandoned and unmaintained, and should not be used. If you want to use Bokeh to display Donut charts, you can use the `annular_wedge` glyph to diplauy to donut pieces explicity:

```
from math import pi

import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.palettes import Category20c
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import cumsum

x = { 'United States': 157, 'United Kingdom': 93, 'Japan': 89, 'China': 63,
    'Germany': 44, 'India': 42, 'Italy': 40, 'Australia': 35,
    'Brazil': 32, 'France': 31, 'Taiwan': 31, 'Spain': 29 }

data = pd.Series(x).reset_index(name='value').rename(columns={'index':'country'})
data['angle'] = data['value']/data['value'].sum() * 2*pi
data['color'] = Category20c[len(x)]

p = figure(plot_height=350)

p.annular_wedge(x=0, y=1, inner_radius=0.2, outer_radius=0.4,
        start_angle=cumsum('angle', include_zero=True), end_angle=cumsum('angle'),
        line_color="white", fill_color='color', legend='country', source=data)

show(p)
```

[image]